# How to add a radio buttons and CheckBoxs in pdf in Print Office Apex?

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I have this code in data source when add button to print report using Print Office Apex

```
`SELECT
    'file1' AS "filename",
    CURSOR(
        SELECT
            f.FOLLOWUP_TITLE AS "SurveyTitle",
            CURSOR(
                SELECT
                    q.QUESTION_NAME AS "Question",
                    CURSOR(
                        SELECT
                            y.OPTION_NAME AS "Answer"
                        FROM
                            FOLLOWUP_OPTIONS_QUESTION y
                        WHERE
                            y.question_id = q.question_id
                        ORDER BY
                            y.OPTION_NAME
                    ) AS "option"
                FROM
                    FOLLOWUP_QUESTION q
                WHERE
                    f.FOLLOWUP_ID = q.FOLLOWUP_ID
                GROUP BY
                    f.FOLLOWUP_TITLE, q.QUESTION_NAME, q.QUESTION_ID, q.QUESTION_TYPE
                ORDER BY
                    CASE 
                        WHEN q.QUESTION_TYPE = 'Select' THEN 1
                        WHEN q.QUESTION_TYPE = 'Multi select' THEN 2
                        WHEN q.QUESTION_TYPE = 'Text' THEN 3
                        ELSE 4
                    END, q.QUESTION_NAME
            ) AS "questions"
        FROM
            FOLLOWUP_FOLLOWSUP f
        WHERE
            f.FOLLOWUP_ID = :P17_FOLLOWUP_ID
    ) AS "data"
FROM
    DUAL;
```

And my template to display this servey inside is

```
{#questions}
    {Question}
    {#option}
        {Answer}
    {/option}
{/questions}
```

It work and display servay but i want to add radio button for every option in question type is select and add checkbox if question type is Multi select and add space like ..... if question type is text ?

Comment: I want to add just a shape in PDF becouse i want to print this pdf and in Apex Office Print Document there is a description about it but it does not work when i try it.